# Groupby a dataframe conditioned on "subset" relationship?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, set, subset

Generate a sample dataframe using:

`import pandas as pd`

`pd.DataFrame({'A': [{'A', 'B'}, {'A', 'B', 'C', 'E'}, {'B', 'D'}, {'C', 'B'}, {'A', 'B', 'D'}, {'X'}], 'B': [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666]})`

which looks like this:

[image]

I need to group by the dataframe according to Column "A" value based on "subset" relationship, i.e.,

- The first group will be including index of 0, 1, 3;
- The second group will be including index of 2, 4;
- The third group will be including index of 5.

Because {'A', 'B'} and {'C', 'B'} are subsets of {'A', 'B', 'C', 'E'}, whereas {'B', 'D'} is a subset of {'A', 'B', 'D'}. {'X'} is not subset of any other values in column A.

Currently, I can only think of an o(n^2) time complexity method, which is similar to the 1st answer below.

For conflicts as pointed out by @mozway in the comments, I will confirm the need ASAP.

Is there any better efficient way to achieve this?

The faster the better.

Thanks!

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question earlier? :-) And what have you tried so far?

Comment: what if you also had a `{A, B, D}` row? what would be the output?

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @user3521970 in the updated example `{'B', 'A'}` is a subset of both `{'A', 'B', 'C', 'E'}` and `{'B', 'D', 'A'}`. How do you choose which one to use? Is there a specific rule of would any of them work?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can compare each set with the <= operator to check if it's a subset. For example:

```
>>> small = {'A', 'B'}
>>> big = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'E'}
>>> small <= big
True
>>> big <= small
False
```

For any given column you can get a True/False Series if a given value is a subset. For example, in your dataframe:

```
>>> df['A'].iloc[0] <= df['A']
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
```

From there, think about how you could use such relations to group. Good luck!

Comment: I think this solution requires a 0(n^2) time. Can be quicker?

Comment: You could create a dictionary-like data structure which adds each of the subsets as values to the larger set keys, i.e. first sort the sets by size (takes n log n time), then add the first element as a key. For each following element, if it's not a subset of a key make it a new key, if it is a subset add it as a value of that key. I think that would end up being O(n log n)? I might be mistaken, though.